# KeyError generating tf records for object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to run the object detection API in tensorflow following this tutorial / accompanying code: https://gilberttanner.com/blog/creating-your-own-objectdetector

When I type `python2 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images_train.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record` into the terminal, I see a file train.record is created in this directory, but I also get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 107, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 96, in main
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 47, in split
    gb = df.groupby(group)
  File "/Users/sofiatomov/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6665, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sofiatomov/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 2152, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/Users/sofiatomov/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 599, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "/Users/sofiatomov/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'filename'
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command:

```
python2 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images_train.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=train.record
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check column names of the csv file.